# QMap values as structs

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

Let's say we have this sample:

```
struct test
{
    QString name;
    int count = 0;
};

QMap<QString,test> map;
test test1;
test1.name = "doc1";
map.insertMulti("pen",test1);

test test2;
test2.name = "doc2";

map.insertMulti("pen",test2);

if(map.contains("pen"))
{
    map.value("pen",test1).count++; // Here goes the error
  //map["pen"].count++; //works but increments count of last inserted struct
}

foreach (test value, map) {
    qDebug() << value.name << " " << value.count;
}
```

So what I am trying to do is check if key is already there then increment the count of the struct I need.

Please advise how to do this properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you should extract a [mcve] before asking here and specifically, "here goes the error" is worthless without the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`value()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#value) returns a constant value that can not be modified, instead You must use an iterator using the [`find()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#find) method:

```
struct Test{
    QString name;
    int count = 0;
};

QMultiMap<QString, Test> map;
Test test;
test.name = "doc1";
map.insert("pen", test);

if(map.contains("pen")){
    qDebug() << "before: " << map.value("pen").count;
    QMultiMap<QString, Test>::iterator it = map.find("pen");
    it->count += 10;
    qDebug() << "after: " << map.value("pen").count;
}
```

Output:

```
before:  0
after:  10
```

**Update:**

In the case of QMap you must use the [operator []](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d) that returns the reference of the stored value:

```
struct Test{
    QString name;
    int count = 0;
};

QMap<QString, Test> map;
Test test1;
test1.name = "doc1";
map.insertMulti("pen",test1);

Test test2;
test2.name = "doc2";
map.insertMulti("pen", test2);

if(map.contains("pen")){
    qDebug() << "before: " << map.value("pen").count;
    map["pen"].count++;
    qDebug() << "after: " << map.value("pen").count;
}
```

Output:

```
before:  0
after:  1
```

**Update:**

You have to use [find()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#find) to get the iterator of the first element with the key, and if you want to access an element with the same key you must increase the iterator.

```
struct Test{
    QString name;
    int count = 0;
};

QMap<QString, Test> map;
Test test1;
test1.name = "doc1";
map.insertMulti("pen",test1);

Test test2;
test2.name = "doc2";
map.insertMulti("pen", test2);

if(map.contains("pen")){
    // get the first item with the key
    QMap<QString, Test>::iterator it = map.find("pen");
    // the next element
    it++;
    // update value
    it->count++;
}

for(const Test & value: map){
    qDebug() << value.name << " " << value.count;
}
```

Output:

```
"doc2"   0
"doc1"   1
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my question before you posted the answer. Please check the new modified one thanks

Comment: I understand but my problem is that I need to increment count for specific struct which is test1 for example. Your result increments count of test2.